# require_once not working on shared server

Tags: php, apache, shared-hosting

I'm moving my open cart website to a shared hosting server. When I log in with FTP, I see my path to the files is /webspace/httpdocs/mydomain.com/

In index.php of Open Cart, there is a line

```
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php');
```

This throws an error. When I do:

```
echo file_exists(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php');
```

I get false. DIR_SYSTEM is returning the correct path - /webspace/httpdocs/mydomain.com/

I have always had dedicated hosting and am used to using paths such as /var/www/mydomain.com/. With shared hosting, so I need to put something before /webspace?

Comment: what this returns? echo DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php'

Comment: Your problem is probably linked to the leading `backslash` which is saying `webspace` should be a subfolder of the root. Which of course it is not on a shared server. As to adding something before webspace, you should never be able to find out what that is, or you could possibly attempt to compromise another site. Use reletive addressing always, as its the only way to ensure portability.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you, that worked. Can you put it as an answer and I will accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably linked to the leading backslash which is saying webspace should be a subfolder of the root.

Which of course it is not on a shared server.

As to adding something before webspace, you should never be able to find out what that is, or you could possibly attempt to compromise another site.

Use reletive addressing always, as its the only way to ensure portability